# Ошибка при становке Laravel в composer

Tags: laravel

ошибка

"You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode."

Comment: Это не текст ошибки

Comment: Как всегда, с mbstring, наверное, проблемы.. Выложите полностью ошибку, та что у Вас это самая последняя и самая бесполезная строка